# Are there any good tools/resources to discover and visualize connections between songs e.g. from a Spotify playlist?

Tags: music, spotify

**Context:** I perform music in a cover band. We have a growing list of over 300 songs (200-ish which we perform and 100-ish works-in-progress), and I maintain this list in a spreadsheet.

A year ago I used [Spotlistr](https://www.spotlistr.com/search/textbox) text import to convert the entire list of covers into a [Spotify playlist](https://open.spotify.com/playlist/38NWp40zBVTosn0nsWW5k9) of the original songs.
Since then, I manually update the Spotify list whenever we add a new song.

Some months later, I used [Exportify](https://exportify.net/) to get all the Spotify metadata and add it into my spreadsheet.

**My question is:**

I wonder if it is possible to see the connections from one song to various others, in order to dynamically select the next song in our performance without having to scroll through the entire list.

I'm thinking of something like the [Spotify Artist Network](https://labs.polsys.net/playground/spotify/), which shows the connections between various artists with a network graph.
I would like to achieve something similar, but linking the *songs* to each other rather than artists - and limited specifically to the songs on my band playlist linked above.

I am a below-average programmer, and I don't know that I could create something like this from scratch - so

1. are there any tools that can do this? AI or otherwise? if not ...
2. what would I need to do in order to do this myself with mediocre programming skill?